# Algebraic methods in pde

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, d-modules, linear-pde

I'm finding myself with a linear, very symetric system of first orders pde with polynomial coefficients. Wandering on the web, i learnt there is some nice alebraic way to deal with it involving D-module, but could not find anything precise.
Could someone explain to me what can i hope? For example, can i obtain a description of all algebraic solutions or that kind of thing?
A readable reference for an outsider would be warmly welcome, too.